# Please explain linux kernel source code directories

Tags: linux, source

Could someone explain how different folders in [linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) are connected?

There a lot of interesting stuff like `/arch`, `/security`, `/samples`, `/crypto` and etc.
Where do this files "go" after compilation?
For example I use Ubuntu. If there any chance to find them in `/usr` or `/sys` folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it ends up in the kernel, `vmlinuz-...` typically in `/boot`, or in modules in `/lib/modules`, with one sub-directory per kernel version. Some of the tools in the `tools` directory end up elsewhere, *e.g.* `perf`. Most of the directories you mention are simply parts of the kernel, organised in various ways: architecture-specific code in `arch`, crypto code in `crypto`, etc. There's also build infrastructure which is only used during the build.

Comment: I have never compiled linux from source that's probably why I don't understand kernel structure... So. Linux starts not in the 'kernel' folder, but in the root folder of git repo, right? But I still can't understand why there so many folders. Is there any need to add filesystems like xfs and ufs  (in the fs folder)?

Comment: @ГригорийШепелев Yes there's a need for xfs and ufs, people do use those filesystems. UFS, for example, is widely used on *BSD systems, so it is useful for Linux to be able to read UFS partitions. When you compile Linux from source you can disable any filesystems you don't think you'll need.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel ok. But there is no ZFS. Is that because it's not like «the classical one»?

Comment: That's because ZFS isn't part of the Linux kernel. Some kernel "drivers" (or modules) are separate projects: ZFS, proprietary GPU drivers such as AMD's Catalyst and NVIDIA's drivers, exFAT...

Comment: @ГригорийШепелев It's because the (Open)ZFS license is not compatible with GPLv2 (or, at least, because the folks at the FSF say so). However, Ubuntu includes ZFS as of 16.04.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel No, ZFS isn't in the Linux kernel source tree (as linked to by the OP) because it's not part of the kernel. The license issue might play a part in that but it's not the only consideration; there are other kernel modules which aren't part of the kernel source tree even though they're licensed under the GPLv2.

Comment: @StephenKitt The license is the main reason why ZFS cannot be mainlined. If it were GPLv2 or BSD, it would undoubtedly have been mainlined a long time ago. ZFS is just that great.

Answer (score 0):

You  didnt find any linux kernel files on /usr and /sys.You should extract linux kernel source code in  /usr/src After compiled linux kernel.You should make modules and install it.config, sysmap,vmlinuz and initrd stored in /boot and all modules stored in .. /lib/modules based on linux kernel release.